# How to run daemons in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I need a docker image that needs to access to a postgres database which needs its daemon to run. Each consequent `RUN` call in Dockerfile uses a new shell and no previous machine state like daemons are available. Currently I use this approach

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    psql -U postgres -c "create database ..."
```

But this approach forces me to start daemon in each `RUN` call which is kinda inconvenient
If I have a program that needs a running daemon which is dependent on other programs I need to care about starting all dependent services too

My task is to build a node server that needs not only database but other software that needs daemons to run as well.
How do i need to design my Dockerfile to be able then to build an image and run it?

Comment: A typical approach is to start services in an entry script or to move the whole DB instance to a separate Docker container, e.g. using docker-compose.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'll take a look at docker-compose